# the continuity of the complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Thank you ver much if anyone could give my any suggestions.I will put the original text first, and my question below.
So the original text is from Brown's *Complex Variables and Applications* Sec.70:

> Theorem. A  power series$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n \tag{1}$$
> represents a continuous function $S(z)$ at each point  inside its cricle of convergence$|z-z_0|=R$

and then here is the textbook proof of this theorem

> To prove this theorem, we let $S_n(z)$ denote the sum of the first $N$ terms of series $(1)$ and write the remainder function
> $$\rho_n(z) = S(z)-S_N(z)\qquad   (|z-z_0|=R)$$
> Then, because
> $$S(z)= S_N(z)+\rho_N(z)$$
> One can see that
> $$|S(z)-S(z_1)|=|S_N(z)-S_N(z_1)+\rho_N(z)-\rho_N(z_1)|$$
> or
> $$|S(z)-S(z_1)|\leq|S_N(z)-S_N(z_1)|+|\rho_N(z)|+|\rho_N(z_1)|\tag{3}$$
> If z is any point lying in some closed disk $|z-z_0|\leq R_0$ whose radius $R_0$ is greater than $|z_1-z|$ but less than the radius $R$ of the circle of convergence of series $(1)$, the uniform convergence stated in Theorem 2, Sec 69, ensures that there is a positive integer $N_{\epsilon}$ such that
> $$ |\rho_N(z)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\quad \text{ whenever }\; N>N_{\epsilon} \tag{4}$$
> In particular, condition $(4)$ holds for each point $z$ in some neighbourhood $|z-z_1|<\delta$ of $z_1$ that is small enough to be contained in the disk $|z-z_0|\leq R_0$.
> **Now the partial sum $S_N(z)$ is a polynomial and is, therefore, continuous at $z_1$ for each value of $N$**, In particular, when $N=N_{\epsilon}+1$, we can choose our $\delta$ so small that
> $$\qquad S_N(z)-S_N(z_1)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\quad \text{ whenever }\; |z-z_1|<\delta.\tag{5}$$

My question is that
Is $S(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ a polynomial?
And if it is, then, why can't we just said that:
"Because $S(z)$ is a polynomial and is, therefore, continuous at $z_1$" just like what the bolded context said?

Comment: "Is $S(z)$ a polynomial?" No, it's not. For example, what is the degree of that as a polynomial?

Comment: $S(z)$ is not a polynomial, but $S_N(z)$ is defined to be the "the sum of the first $N$ terms of series" ie $S_N(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n (z-z_0)^n$, which is a polynomial. The idea is to approximate the power series by a polynomial and use the continuity of the polynomial to help prove continuity of the power series.

Comment: this is just an application of a general theorem about uniform convergence and continuity https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/funseq/proofs/uconvcont.html#:~:text=Theorem%208.2.-,3%3A%20Uniform%20Convergence%20preserves%20Continuity,is%20also%20continuous%20on%20D.